# Exception occurred during [UpdateQueryDefinition]

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, sql, soap, marketingcloudapi

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm trying to update a QueryDefinition (SQL Query) using this Soap Envelope.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
<fueloauth>{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options>
            </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
                </PartnerKey>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">25b11915-5dd7-41f2-83b4-3b7d60d4b7ff</ObjectID>
                <Client><ID>52300XXXX</ID></Client>
      
                <CustomerKey>3fc16fbc-f5e3-423c-98f2-2933f3719999</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Test Query</Name>
                <Description>Test</Description>
   
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I was able to create the same query using this envelope except that it was a CreateRequest instead of UpdateRequest. I also updated the SOAPAction headers to use Update instead of create (see image).

[image]

Based on others who have had this issue, it seems to be that all you need to update a query is the ObjectID, which I have. I've tripled checked that it is the correct one. My package does not have all permissions enabled, but I believe I have the right ones, and after all, I was able to create the Query so it stands to reason I'd be able to update as well.

Can anyone think of anything I might be missing? I've tried this as patch, post and put. Post is the only one that doesn't give me an error saying the verb is not allowed (I'm using postman).

Comment: Does it tell you what the exception is?

Comment: ErrorCode 2, very generic

Comment: Btw, I use rest for this and it's a lot easier to construct the request.

Comment: @caspar can you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an undocumented REST API (which I think is here to stay because it's pretty extensive and the Query Tool AppExchange app uses it)

```
//get a query by id. Uses a custom apex class to handle the respose JSON.
public static MCQueryDefinitionResponse getQuery(String queryId){
    //GET /automation/v1/queries/{{queryID}}
    String authToken = getAccessToken();
    String endpoint = REST_Base_URI__c + REST_AUTOMATIONS_QUERY + '/' + queryId;
    String jsonResult = performRequest(authToken, endpoint, 'GET');
    MCQueryDefinitionResponse response = (MCQueryDefinitionResponse)JSON.deserialize(jsonResult, MCQueryDefinitionResponse.class);
    return response;
}
```

Other things you can do include -

Update:

```
PATCH /automation/v1/queries/{{queryID}}
```

Run:

```
POST /automation/v1/queries/{{queryID}}/actions/start/
```

Get is running:

```
GET /automation/v1/queries/{{queryID}}/actions/isrunning/
```

Get data from a DE:

```
GET data/v1/customobjectdata/key/{{DEKEY}}/rowset
String endpoint = REST_Base_URI__c + REST_DE_BY_KEY.replace('{{DEKEY}}', deKey) + '?$filter=EmailAddress%20eq%20"' + urlEncodedEmail + '"';
```

Comment: Thanks, even though mine works, I marked yours as correct because it's a better solution!

Comment: It's cool eh! You can also find more stuff by using postman or workbench to query like this: `/automation/v1/queries/` which gives you all possible queries/ paths

Comment: Here is a link to a blog post I wrote on this that might help give some added context (https://gortonington.com/how-to-interact-with-query-activities-via-rest-api/). Just do note that undocumented endpoints are use at your own risk so would not use for anything in production

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have to include the DE target in order to do any kind of update. This sucks because now I have to retrieve that info first, but oh well.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
<fueloauth>{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options>
            </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
                </PartnerKey>
                <ObjectID>25b11915-5dd7-41f2-83b4-3b7d60d4b7ff</ObjectID>      
                <CategoryID>843897</CategoryID>          
                <DataExtensionTarget>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
                    </PartnerKey>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                    </ObjectID>
                    <CustomerKey>70646C0C-FB4F-43FF-9DE6-30F4B9CA3FDD</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>test</Name>
                </DataExtensionTarget>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```